# How can I get the probability of each predicted values in Python in multiclass?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am currently working on a disease prediction machine learning model. I used Random Forest Classifier in my model, and now I am trying to get probabilities of predicted values, but the code gives me an error. In this program, I want to get the probabilities of "each" prediction specifically. For example, I entered the symptoms to predict the disease and the predicted disease is "Allergy". Then, I want my program to show the probability of the predicted disease "Allergy" as a percent, but the program gives errors like "classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and unknown targets". I guess I need to use confusion matrix to show the probabilities, but it also gives the same error about the multiclass problem. More clearly, I just want to show the probability of each predicted value as "percent". For instance, the probability of Allergy disease is 90%, etc. How can I do that and how can I solve my problem?

Here the relevant codes:

```
p=pickle_model.predict([[22,8,50,9,20,47,50,38,0,0,0]])
```

```
actual=np.array((22,8,50,9,20,47,50,38,0,0,0))
```

```
pred=pickle_model.predict_proba([[p,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

In the code block below:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import sklearn.metrics as mt
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
print(accuracy_score(actual, p, normalize=True, sample_weight=None))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-e8980bf68410> in <module>
      3 from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
      4 from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
----> 5 print(accuracy_score(actual, p, normalize=True, sample_weight=None))
      6 #precision, recall, fscore, support =
      7 #score(y_test, p)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize, sample_weight)
    200 
    201     # Compute accuracy for each possible representation
--> 202     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    203     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
    204     if y_type.startswith('multilabel'):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     81     y_pred : array or indicator matrix
     82     """
---> 83     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
     84     type_true = type_of_target(y_true)
     85     type_pred = type_of_target(y_pred)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    260     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    261     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 262         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    263                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    264 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [11, 1]
```

Also, the other error that I get in this code block is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-774dbd6b46f7> in <module>
      8 
      9 # specificity
---> 10 tn, fp, fn, tp = mt.confusion_matrix(actual, predict).ravel()
     11 specificity = tn / (tn+fp)
     12 print(specificity)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels, sample_weight, normalize)
    294 
    295     """
--> 296     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
    297     if y_type not in ("binary", "multiclass"):
    298         raise ValueError("%s is not supported" % y_type)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     90 
     91     if len(y_type) > 1:
---> 92         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
     93                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
     94  
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass and unknown targets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking is `predict_proba()`.

The input of this function has to be exactly the inputs of your model trained. It must have the same inputs of the function `predict()`.

If this part of your code worked to you (since you not reported any error):

```
p=pickle_model.predict([[22,8,50,9,20,47,50,38,0,0,0]])
```

This should work also:

```
p=pickle_model.predict_proba([[22,8,50,9,20,47,50,38,0,0,0]])
```

**Note:** Be aware of "[]", maybe you should have to delete someone.

Comment: I tried as you said, but it gives me the error: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [11, 1]`. I tried it like: `print(accuracy_score(actual, p, normalize=True, sample_weight=None))` maybe should I use another thing instead of "actual"?

Comment: The problem is your format. Can you please print `actual` and `p`. They must have the same shape, which has to match the format of the trained model. Maybe reshape will be a good option. [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) there is a clear example